# Prove that cosine serie evaluates to zero by induction and double differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I had a linear algebra exam with this question which I had trouble solving. Here it is:

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ such that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 \neq \ldots \neq \lambda_n$. Show by induction over $n$ that if
>
> $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \mu_i \cos(\lambda_i x) = 0$$
>
> then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \ldots = \mu_n = 0$.
>
> Hint: you may need to differentiate the expression twice. Taking the second derivative does not change the linear dependence of the vectors involved.

First of all, I have no clue why it is hinted to differentiate the expression twice. I dit it, and I got

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} -\mu_i (\lambda_i)^2 \cos(\lambda_i x) = 0$$

which did not really help me understand why I would need to do this anyway. Then, I just constructed a silly sequence with

$$\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2} \pi, \lambda_2 = \frac{1 + 2^{2 - 1}}{2} \pi, \lambda_3 = \frac{1 + 2^{3 - 1}}{2} \pi, \ldots, \lambda_n = \frac{1 + 2^{n - 1}}{2} \pi$$

so that if we choose $x = 1$, we obtain $\cos(\lambda_1) = \cos(\lambda_2) = \ldots = \cos(\lambda_n) = 0$. Then we could have positive values for $\mu_i$ and it does not matter since the cosine will always evaluate to zero in this case.

Note: I know my reasoning *is* faulty. I just want to know what is faulty.

---

The question does not explicitly mention the domain for $\cos(\lambda_i x)$ must be *non-degenerate*, like $\mathbb{R}$. In my reasoning, the interval is *degenerate* since I have chosen a singleton with $x \in \{1\}$.

Comment: The equality to zero (which you use to reduce zero coefficients) is for all $x$; differentiating twice allows to eliminate a term so you can apply induction

Comment: @Conrad you mean factoring out the squared part? Yes, but why does it relate to the first expression then

Comment: the solution below is how you do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed non-zero $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$ let $f_i(x) = \cos(\lambda_i x)$. The statement you should prove is:

> If $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ are distinct, then $f_1\dotsc,f_n$ are linearly independent.

(This is only true, if $f_i$ does not vanish completely, that is, its domain must be sufficiently large, like an interval with positive length.)

*Proof by induction over $n$:*

For $n=1$ it is trivial, as $f_1\ne 0$. (Here you need a sufficiently large domain.)

Assume the statement is valid for $n-1$. Let $\mu_1,\dotsc,\mu_n$ be given with
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i f_i = 0. $$
We want to prove $\mu_1=\dotsb=\mu_n=0$.

By differentiating the equation twice, we obtain
$$ \Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i f_i \Bigr)'' = \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i f_i'' = \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i (-\lambda_i^2 f_i) = 0. $$
Thus, we have
$$ 0 = \lambda_n^2 \Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i  f_i\Bigr) - \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i \lambda_i^2 f_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mu_i(\lambda_n^2 - \lambda_i^2) f_i. $$
Now, as $f_1,\dotsc,f_{n-1}$ are linearly independent by induction hypothesis, we have $\mu_i(\lambda_n^2 - \lambda_i^2) = 0$ for $1\le i\le n-1$. As the $\lambda_i$'s are distinct, it follows $(\lambda_n^2 - \lambda_i^2) \ne 0$ and $\mu_i = 0$ for $1\le i \le n-1$. It remains
$$ \mu_n f_n = 0. $$
Again, as $f_n\ne 0$ (sufficiently large domain), it follows $\mu_n = 0$.

Comment: @eigenslacker: there is no radius of convergence. It is a finite sum, not a series.

Comment: @eigenslacker: I am not sure that I understand your question. But the $f_i$ does not vanish by differentiation.

Comment: I meant why does the index is not shifted when you take the second derivative of the sum?

Comment: @eigenslacker: why should it?

Comment: You can mention this fact in your answer if you want, I think it’s important and worth mentioning

Comment: @eigenslacker: If you differentiate $f+g$ you get $f' + g'$. There is no rule to make one summand vanish. It only happens, if it happens to be $f'=0$ or $g'=0$.

Comment: @eigenslacker: Do you mean $n$? I can not really follow.

Comment: Never mind for that. Also, if I carefully choose lambda to be in a sequence of $\pi/2$, how does the $f_i$ can be linearly independent?

Comment: They are all pair wise different and the implication become false

Comment: @eigenslacker: It depends on the domain of $f_i$. You are fine if the domain is an interval like $[0, 1]$. However, say for $n=2$, $\lambda_1 = \pi/2$ and $\lambda_2 = 3\pi/2$, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly dependent on $\{1, -1\}$. Because $f_1 = f_2 = 0$.

Comment: In this case, how the implication can be true??? This is a valid situation where the lambdas are all pair wise different and we still get linearly dependent functions

Comment: @eigenslacker: No it is not. I added a warning in my answer that the statement in your question is not complete. I suspect the domain is simply $\mathbb R$, which is fine.

Comment: Isn’t my sequence of $\pi/2$ in my own question a perfect counter example?

Comment: @eigenslacker: no. It is only a counter example, if you have specified the domain. Like I said, it depends on the domain.

Comment: Yes but it’s never mentioned in that exam question that the interval for $f_i$ must be non-degenerate

Comment: @eigenslacker: Like I said, I suspect the domain is simply $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh I got it. Each $f_i$ has its own domain and each domain for each $f_i$ must be non-degenerate. Not counting the other in the process. Well, that’s fine

Comment: @eigenslacker: No. $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ have a common domain, say $D$. That set needs to have so many points such that each $f_i$ is non-zero on $D$. That is, there must be at least one $x_i\in D$ with $f_i(x_i) \ne 0$. That is surely the case if $D$ is an interval with positive length (that is non-degenerate).

Comment: Also, now that I get the first part, the question hints to take the second derivative since we can get the cosine function back and that the derivative is a linear operator that does not change the linear dependence of the vectors involved, am I right?

Comment: @eigenslacker: yes

Comment: As for the domain $D$, I get the sense that the domain is very large but what if each points happens to fall on the special values nullifying each $f_i$? It’s still possible even though the domain is infinite

Comment: Also can you mention that the derivative is linear operator that does not change the linear dependence of the vectors involved, and that here we have a particular situation where the second derivative happens to yields back the function in the first expression. I think it’s very helpful to explain why the hint asked this. Thank you

Comment: @eigenslacker: each $f_i$ has infinite many zeros. They are isolated. But on interval with positive length $f_i$ has at least one "non-zero".

Comment: The question should have mentioned that anyway, it’s not obvious per se